# Board game dice-unrecognized

Tags: identify-this-game

I found a white die in our box of board games and I don't know what game it belongs to.

It has six sides with white numbers on them; 1 - 6, one number to a side. Each number has an orange circle around it.

Does anyone know what game this die might belong to?

Comment: Also, could you please provide a picture of the die?

Comment: This is hopeless without  a picture.

Comment: A white number in an orange circle? [Like this](http://www.pd4pic.com/images800_/one-circle-white-orange-free-number-numbers.png)?

Comment: Quick notes: "six sided die" can just be described as "d6". Is it "normal" die size, or something bigger/smaller? Is it a solid orange circle with a white number inside, or just an orange circle line with another color inside and then white letters? What color is outside/inside the circle?]